# Do I need to composite this image (frame), or am I over complicating the situation?

Tags: html, css

I have been tasked with a build that includes the following design. A gold frame with corner decorations.

[image]

Now, the divs this frame will be connected to will have a varied height and width. Using, for example, `object-fit: contain` would not work because the corner decorations will stretch and look misshapen.

The only real method I can think of is to break down each element and position them correctly. So as a quick example:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="frame">
        <div class="corner corner__top--left"></div>
        <div class="line line__left"></div>
        <div class="corner corner__top--right"></div>
        <div class="line line__right"></div>
        <div class="corner corner__bottom--left"></div>
        <div class="line line__top"></div>
        <div class="corner corner__bottom--right"></div>
        <div class="line line__bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.corner {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}

.corner__top--left {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.corner__top--right {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.corner__bottom--left {
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.corner__bottom--right {
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
}

.line__left {
  left: 20px;
  top: 70px;
  height: calc(100% - 140px);
  width: 5px;
}

.line__right {
  right: 20px;
  top: 70px;
  height: calc(100% - 140px);
  width: 5px;
}

.line__top {
  left: 70px;
  top: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 140px);
  height: 5px;
}

.line__bottom {
  left: 70px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 140px);
  height: 5px;
}
```

I'm wondering am I not seeing the wood for the trees and missing a glaringly obvious solution to this? Or is my only solution to composite the image in this way to retain the correct ratios?

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Use CSS `border-image` which lets you slice-up a single image into resizable borders (it supports both stretching and repetition): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using double-underscores `__` and double-dashes `--`  interchangeably?

Comment: No particular reason, its just the format I use

Comment: I'd say the easiest and perhaps the best way is to save this frame as a .png / .webp file and get it as a background of the tile you're building using position relative and absolute. Just make sure to use z-index properly and get the actual tile content in front.

Comment: @MichałDroździk no the ebst an easiest way would be a svg. it would render smoothly no matter of the aspect ratio or size unlike a large png. Also no position relative and absolute needed if you use it as background in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Just use `border-image`.

  - The `border-image` property lets you use a single image and slice it up into a 9-grid where each cell represents a stretchable (or repeatable) border side.
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image
- I used [MDN's `border-image` generator tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Border-image_generator), [with your example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LH7a.png), to generate this demo example below:
- Screenshot proof:

  - Tall elements: 
     [image]
  - *Smol* elements: 
     [image]

---

```css
section {
    border-style       : solid;   
    border-image-slice : 88 99 98 105 fill;
    border-image-width : 88px 99px 98px 105px;
    border-image-outset: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    
    /* stretch or repeat the sides, as per your preference: */
    border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
    border-image-repeat: repeat repeat;
    
    border-image-source: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LH7a.png");
    
    padding: 100px;
}

textarea {
    resize: both !important;
}
```

```html
<section>

   <textarea rows="10" cols="20">Resize me!</textarea>

</section>
```